# Trouble with Lagrangian and Newtonian mechanics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

I'm a pure mathematician and I was doing some physics for fun. I was trying to obtain the equations of motion of a particle moving along a curve $y(x)$ under the effect of gravitational force which constant $g$ depends on the heigth from the $x$ axis, ie $g=g(y)$. I take $q=x(t)$ as the generalized coordinate, and used the Euler-Lagrange equations to obtain $$\left(1+y'^2\right)\ddot{x}+\left((yg'+g)+\dot{x}^2y''\right)y'=0.$$ Where $y'$ and $g'$ denote their derivatives on $x$. Now i wanted to prove the veracity of the expresion by taking a simple example like the inclined plane with slope $1$. So i set $y(x)=x$ and $g(y)$ constant, obtaining the simple equation $$2\ddot{x}+g=0,$$ but the equation of move on the inclined plane with the classical mechanics is $$ma=-mg\sin \theta,$$ where $\theta=45^º$, son $$ma=-mg\sqrt{2}/2\implies \sqrt{2}a+g=0.$$ What's happening?

Comment: It looks like you might have assumed that the potential energy should be $U = m g(y) y$?  That's not true.  You should have $U = m \int_0^y g(y) dy$, since that's how potential energy is defined (as minus the integral of the force, or in other words such that $\vec{F} = - \nabla U$.)  I don't think this is the source of your current problem, but it's something to watch out for in the future.

Comment: Consider to include Lagrangian for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is that $\ddot{x}$ from the Lagrangian is not the same as the acceleration $a$ typically found in introductory mechanics problems.  Rather, $\ddot{x}$ is the $x$-component of the vector $\vec{a}$, and $a$ is the magnitude of the vector $\vec{a}$.  So for an object accelerating down a 45° plane, we have $\ddot{x} = a_x = a \cos 45^\circ = a/\sqrt{2}$, resolving the seeming inconsistency.